# No compiler errors and a blanc test scene

Tags: actionscript-3

I made a flash file called airRaid, and 2 classes. They are in the same folder. If i test the scene, even if i write completely wrong code, I get no errors.

The code is ment to play a movieClip. I linked it properly.

So i have the airRaid flash file.

A VoertuigRaid class. If I remove half of the code, et gives no errors, the only thing i see is a blanc test scene.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class VoertuigRaid extends MovieClip
    {

        public function VoertuigRaid()
            {
                var a:Voertuig = new Voertuig("left", 50, 200);
                addChild(a);
            }
    }
}
```

And a Voertuig class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Voertuig extends MovieClip 
            {
                private var dx:Number;          //Snelheid en richting
                private var lastTime:int;       //Animatie tijd

        public function Voertuig(side:String, speed:Number, altitude:Number)
            {
                if (side == "left")
                    {
                        this.x = -50;       //Start aan de linkerkant
                        dx = speed          //Vlieg naar rechts
                        this.scaleX = -1;   //omdraaien
                    }
                else if (side == "right")
                    {
                        this.x = 50;        //Start aan de linkerkant
                        dx = -speed;        //Vlieg naar links
                        this.scaleX = 1;    //Niet omdraaien
                    }
                this.y = altitude           //Verticale positie van het voertuig

                //Kies een willekeurig vliegtuig
                this.gotoAndStop(Math.floor(Math.random()*5+1));

                //Animatie voorbereiden
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveVoertuig);
                lastTime = getTimer();
            }

        public function moveVoertuig(event:Event)
            {
                //Tijd moet passeren
                var timePassed:int = getTimer() -lastTime;
                lastTime += timePassed/1000;

                //Beweeg voertuig
                this.x += dx*timePassed/1000;

                //check to see it off screen
                if ((dx < 0) && (x < -50))
                    {
                        deleteVoertuig();
                    }
                else if ((dx > 0) && (x > 700))
                    {
                        deleteVoertuig();
                    }
            }
        public function deleteVoertuig()
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveVoertuig);
                MovieClip(parent).removeVoertuig(this);
                parent.removeChild(this);
            }
        public function voertuigHit()
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveVoertuig);
                MovieClip(parent).removeVoertuig(this);
                gotoAndPlay(ontploffing);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the details you posted as incomplete and out of track. However assuming a few things like you are trying to connect a movieclip in library with the **Voertuig** Class,

If you want the library movieclip to be used as well as extend with the above functions, set **Class** and not **Base Class** of the movieclip. Something like this:

[image]